# How to make sure downloaded data is different before assigning it

Tags: image, swift, nsurlsession

I have this function that gets a random image from a server, but it seems it does not want to update all the time, I'm thinking it thinks the data has not changed, when it loads a new image on every request. Here is my code, is there any way to make sure (or tell Swift) the data is different before assigning it to the image?

```
func getNewImage() {

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://weboctopi.com/randomcuteimages/rotate.php")!

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            self.downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!)!

            self.imagePlaceholder.setImage(self.downloadedImage)

        } else {

            print(error)

        }

    }

    task.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a URL caching problem, you can use a custom configuration for cache busting:

```
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
config.URLCache = nil // don't cache

let task = NSURLSession(configuration: config).dataTaskWithURL(...
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference, I'm thinking it is the rotate.php script itself. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason your image is not updating is because the closure is executed on a background thread and UIKit updates need to be on the main thread. Adding this change to your code should fix the issue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
  self.imagePlaceholder?.image = downloadedImage
})
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference, I'm thinking it is the rotate.php script itself. But thank you.